# Programmaticaly show error message on field with KendoReact

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

I have created a server side validation system, and I should hook it to my application made with KendoRect.

I'm looking for a method like:

```
setFieldError ('field', 'Message error');
```

to show the red error message in the correct form field.

Idea?